# WebBrowser errors when loading embedded YouTube videa

Tags: c#, youtube, web-control

With the latest Flash version (19.x), whenever I load an embedded YouTube video in a WebBrower control, it throws back a script error (line 0, char 0, code 0) and end up with a black screen where the video should be.  If I copy and paste the url into IE or Firefox, it works fine.

Test steps are simple - create a blank Forms/WPF project, add in a WebBrower, and point it to an embedded video (for example "https://www.youtube.com/embed/afeAUndotas").

Any ideas?  Note - I'm not interested in simply suppressing the popup using ScriptErrorsSuppressed, I would like the video to actually load.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. WebBrower control emulates IE7 by default. [Try this  workaround.](http://www.cyotek.com/blog/configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-internet-explorer-webbrowser-control)